# Fetch Values of same name item, without repeating item name?

Tags: php

I am making a page of my products, in which i have many products with having same names but different specifications and prices.

PHP code:

```
<code>
        $SelectList = "SELECT a.p_id, a.dis,a.name,b.p_id,b.rate 
            FROM tst1 a 
            INNER JOIN max b 
            ON a.p_id = b.p_id GROUP BY name";
    $Query = mysql_query($SelectList) or die(mysql_error());
    $Num_rows = mysql_num_rows($Query);
    $array = array();

    while($Data=mysql_fetch_assoc($Query))
        {
            $array['name'][] = $Data['name'];
            $array['rate'][] = $Data['rate'];
            $array['dis'][] = $Data['dis'];
        }

</code>

<code>
<table border="1">
    <thead>
            <th>Description</th>
            <th>Unit</th>
            <th>Qty</th>
            <th>Rate</th>
    </thead>
            <tr>
            <td colspan="0">BUTTERFLY VALVES</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
            <td>65 mm</td>
            <td>Nos</td>
            <td>15</td>
            <td>40%</td>
    </tr>
            <tr>
            <td colspan="0">BUTTERFLY VALVES</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
            <td>85 mm</td>
            <td>Nos</td>
            <td>45</td>
            <td>40%</td>
    </tr>
           <tr>
            <td colspan="0">WASHER VALVES</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
            <td>32 mm</td>
            <td>Nos</td>
            <td>95</td>
            <td>30%</td>
    </tr>
    </table>
</code>
```

So what i want is, if product name is same so just fetch only "name" once, and its "unit, qty & rates" all of them.

```
<code>
<table style="position:relative; top:10px; bottom:10px; left:200px" border="1">
    <thead>
            <th>Description</th>
            <th>Unit</th>
            <th>Qty</th>
            <th>Rate</th>
    </thead>
            <tr>
            <td colspan="0">BUTTERFLY VALVES</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
            <td>65 mm</td>
            <td>Nos</td>
            <td>15</td>
            <td>40%</td>

            <td>85 mm</td>
            <td>Nos</td>
            <td>45</td>
            <td>40%</td>
    </tr>
           <tr>
            <td colspan="0">WASHER VALVES</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
            <td>32 mm</td>
            <td>Nos</td>
            <td>95</td>
            <td>30%</td>
    </tr>
    </table>
</code>
```

Comment: you should use `sub queries`...

Comment: I have used, group by but only one filed is fetching. not all....

Comment: make array for each product and print it by loop

Comment: in this case `group by` will not help you out .. practically `group by` just returns single result for repeated value...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You may use either `distinct` or `group by` operator in your SQL to do so.

Usage of `distinct` looks like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT column_name,column_name
FROM table_name;
```

You may take a look at [this](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_distinct.asp) example of `distinct`.

Usage of `group by` looks like this:

```
SELECT column_name, aggregate_function(column_name)
FROM table_name
WHERE column_name operator value
GROUP BY column_name;
```

Here is an [example](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp) of `group by`.

I hope this helps.

Comment: @user3409091 `group by` or `distinct` will get all unqiue products from your table. Then you can do a SQL query to SELECT the records for each of those distinct products returned, and print them using php.

Comment: @user3409091 if you want you may take a look at this code snippet which is driven from your question https://dpaste.de/Wn3H

Answer (score 0):

check this `subquery`.. this will help you out..

```
$qry = mysqli_query("select * from product group by name");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($qry))
{
    echo "<tr><td colspan="0">'".$row['name']."'</td></tr>";
    $qry2 = mysqli_query("select * from product where name = '".$row['name']."'");
    echo "<tr>";
    while($row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($qry2))
    {
         echo "<td>'".$row2['mm']."'</td><td>'".$row2['nos']."'</td><td>'".$row2['qty']."'</td><td>'".$row2['percentage']."'</td>";
    }
    echo "</tr>";
}
```

Comment: sorry.. check the edit.. I have put `$row` instead of `$row2` in the other query... and you will need to modify the table and field names as per your table structure...